# List of free Ubuntu books

Tags: ebooks, books

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.

What free ebooks do you recommend to learn more about Ubuntu?

*One book per answer, please - vote answers up/down as you feel appropriate. If you feel the book is biased towards/good for particular tasks, please mention them.*

Comment: This needs to be transformed into a community wiki

Comment: This one is also nice in pdf and ebook format : https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/495652

Answer (score 15):

[**Getting Started with Ubuntu**](http://ubuntu-manual.org/)  (The Ubuntu Manual)

[**Bash - Guide for beginners**](http://writers.fultus.com/garrels/ebooks/Machtelt_Garrels_Bash_Guide_for_Beginners_2nd_Ed.pdf) (On the command line used in Linux, PDF)

[**Linux - Inside the boot process**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linuxboot/) (IBM manual in HTML and PDF)

[**Linux - Network Administration guide**](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/nag2.pdf)

And if you're a masochist, don't forget the ultimate manual for Linux: 
[**Linux - Advanced Administration**](http://ftacademy.org/materials/fsm/2) (Kernel, local/network/server admin, ... **545 pages of knowledge! :-)**)

Comment: Thanks. If you know about more such books, please list them here.

Comment: Sorry I duped this, I didn't recognize that title. You might want to add "(The Ubuntu Manual)" beside "Getting Started with Ubuntu". I deleted my post. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: The Ubuntu Manual is good for new users and people who want to learn more about Ubuntu.

Comment: Can someone update the link for Bash - Guide for beginners?

Answer (score 9):

The [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/) is worth a look as well.

Answer (score 6):

### [The Ubuntu Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ubuntu).

Comment: I think this book needs improvement. We must try and improve it.

Answer (score 6):

The guys who wrote the Server Documentation in the help have done a great job as well: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/index.html, it is also available in PDF.  The good thing is this documentation gets updated every release by the Documentation team

Comment: Yes, just change the release number in the link to get the latest version.

Comment: dead link, please update

Answer (score 2):

"A Complete Beginner’s Manual for Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx)" is available at

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/download-free-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-pdf-guide.html

Answer (score 2):

It is for Ubuntu 9.10,but still relevant..

[Karmic Guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/makeuseof-downloads/#karmic)

For Ubuntu 10.04, you grab Ubuntu Manual from

[Getting Started with Ubuntu 10.04](http://ubuntu-manual.org/)

Answer (score 1):

There is one in **German** available by [Galileo Computing](http://ubuntu.haas.homelinux.net/index.htm) for Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. It can also be downloaded and purchased as a real book. Most of the stuff in there is targeted to beginners.

There are also some [videos](http://www.galileocomputing.de/presse/pressemeldungen/gp/pmID-80) available for the book, but they are outdated by now.