# Are there any good books for new Ubuntu users?

Tags: community, documentation

I recently installed Ubuntu in my uncle's laptop. He seems to like it and he is asking me for some good Ubuntu books for beginners. I was thinking about The Official Ubuntu Book. Any other suggestions would be very much appreciated.

He comes from a Windows background if that would help.

Comment: Please see also: http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/575/list-of-free-ubuntu-books

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've read lots of good books about Ubuntu and Linux in the past few months. This is the first great book.

— Arsgeek.com review of Beginning Ubuntu Linux, Second Edition

Keir Thomas walks you through the whole Ubuntu experience from beginning to end, comforting you with a calm voice when you might be feeling a bit lost ... He has done a great and thorough job.

— Free Software Magazine review of Beginning Ubuntu Linux, Second Edition

Winner of a Linux Journal Editor's Choice 2006 award (first edition)!

Beginning Ubuntu Linux, Second Edition updates the best-selling and award-winning first edition. It's the perfect guide for those switching to the world's favorite Linux. The new edition has been thoroughly updated to cover technology introduced in the 6.10 release.

In the 680+ fully illustrated pages, you'll learn how to install Linux, set up your hardware and software, customize the desktop experience, browse the Web and send/receive e-mail, play back audio and video, edit digital images, use the OpenOffice.org office suite, and more.

Additionally, you'll discover how to perform vital maintenance tasks, such as securing your computer against hackers, updating online, optimizing your system, installing and managing software, backing up, accessing your computer remotely, scheduling tasks, and more.

A whole third of the book is dedicated to Linux internals, including managing system processes and working at the command line. Two appendixes pre a glossary of Linux terms and an index of commands that can be used to control Ubuntu.

Beginning Ubuntu Linux, Second Edition is a complete, comprehensive, and unbiased guide to getting the most from Ubuntu.
DVD-ROM

Beginning Ubuntu Linux, Second Edition features a unique DVD-ROM companion disk containing the full Ubuntu installation that you can install on your computer. A full installation guide is pred in the book. Also included on the DVD-ROM are the Ubuntu sister projects, such as Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Edubuntu, and others. Both the long-term support and recent 6.10 releases of all projects are pred.
In Detail Part 1: Introducing the World of Linux

Opening the book are several chapters pring a brief but complete history of Linux. You'll learn about the key figures in the Linux movement and discover why the politics behind free software are so important.
Part 2: Installing Ubuntu

Here you'll find a fully illustrated guide to both installing Ubuntu on your computer and initially preparing the computer for Ubuntu. Detailed screenshots guide you through every step. In addition, there's a problem-solving chapter pring solutions for the most common issues.
Part 3: The No-Nonsense Getting Started Guide

The six chapters of Part 3 take you from zero to hero in as little time as possible. You'll learn what's what on the Ubuntu desktop and how to customize Ubuntu to suit your workflow. You'll be introduced to Linux replacements for your favorite Windows programs, and you'll be introduced to the Linux file system, so you can start working straightaway.
Part 4: The Shell and Beyond

The five chapters in Part 4 introduce the heart of Linux: the command line. You'll be introduced to the BASH shell, and a full rundown of the Linux filesystem is pred. You'll learn how to work with text files. The closing chapters of this section teach pro-level tricks you can use at the command line to work more efficiently.
Part 5: Multimedia

Here you'll learn how to set up Ubuntu to work with common audio and video files that you might have used under Windows or Macintosh. Then you'll be introduced to Ubuntu's audio and video playback software. Additionally, a complete guide to image editing and digital image management is pred.
Part 6: Office Tasks

The seven chapters in this section pre a comprehensive guide to the OpenOffice.org office suite. You'll learn how to undertake common tasks using the word processor, spreadsheet, presentations package, and database applications. Additionally, a complete guide to using Ubuntu's e-mail and personal information manager is pred.
Part 7: Keeping your System Running

The six chapters in this part of the book pick up from Part 4 and expand on various system management/command-line skills. You'll learn how to perform vital maintenance tasks, such as managing users, or installing and removing software. It's in this part of the book that you'll really learn your Linux stripes!

Answer (score 5):

A good start is the recently published ubuntu manual "Getting Started with Ubuntu 10.04", made by the community: http://ubuntu-manual.org/

It is available for free as a PDF, but you can also order a printed version for less than 10$ at Lulu.com: http://www.lulu.com/product/paperback/getting-started-with-ubuntu-1004/10793559

Answer (score 3):

You certainly took a good step and joining here. Asking question would be beneficial to both you and people who come after you.

I have found this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470589884) to be especially useful, bit outdated but still extremely useful. By Neal Krawetz

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Kung Fu :

> Ubuntu builds on a solid base of
>   Debian Linux to create an
>   award-winning operating system that's
>   light-years ahead of its competitors.
>   Ubuntu consistently tops lists of the
>   most popular Linuxes amongst
>   professionals and enthusiasts; Dell
>   recently embraced Ubuntu in its
>   product lines after a user survey
>   indicated overwhelming public support.
>
> Ubuntu Kung Fu pres hints, hacks,
>   tweaks and tricks for every level of
>   user. Guaranteed to be free of the
>   usual dross that fills tips books,
>   Ubuntu Kung Fu is written to be
>   entertaining and, above all, readable.
>   Its 300+ concise tips utilize and
>   exploit hidden or lesser-known
>   features to boost day-to-day
>   productivity. You'll also find tips on
>   tweaking Ubuntu, wrangling the system
>   into shape, optimizing, enhancing
>   security, and lots more. Learn what
>   extraordinary things can be done with
>   Ubuntu.
>
> Written with the migrating Windows or
>   Mac OS X user in mind, Ubuntu Kung Fu
>   avoids the usual Linux/Unix folklore
>   that can send most of us to sleep. The
>   tips have one aim--to produce results
>   as quickly as possible, in an
>   environment where the reader can
>   polish their skills as they read. This
>   is the Linux book for the rest of us.

Comment: This was copied and pasted directly from [the Amazon product description](http://www.amazon.com/dp/ASIN/1934356220#productDescription.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also find some great free Ubuntu books here: [List of free Ubuntu books](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575/list-of-free-ubuntu-books)

Answer (score 1):

**The Ubuntu Pocket Guide**

Available in print or for free in PDF form. Written for Ubuntu Intrepid, it is still very relevant for Lucid Lynx (at time of posting) and most likely for the next few releases too.

*"Written for anybody switching to Ubuntu, particularly former Windows users, Ubuntu Pocket Guide and Reference assumes zero Linux knowledge. It provides the wisdom of the expert user and concisely conveys core competencies."*

http://www.ubuntupocketguide.com

Answer (score 0):

A PDF download "A Complete Beginner’s Manual for Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx)" is available at:

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/download-free-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-pdf-guide.html