# User guide for users migrating from Windows?

Tags: programming, windows-7, documentation

I am new user for ubuntu. I want to use ubuntu for my python development.
I used windows7 for .net development.

Is there any guide which help me in migration from Windows to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 10):

Another nice document is the [Ubuntu Manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org)

Although the latest version is written for 10.04, it's still not that 'old' and you can find some interesting information there to help you.

Another very helpful document, if interested as a power user to learn some info on server applications is the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/serverguide.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

Download this **[Ubuntu Pocket Guide](http://www.ubuntupocketguide.com/download_main.html)**.

Also look at the following links,

- **[Ubuntu Guide](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aMaverick)**
- **[Switching to Ubuntu from Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows)**
- **[Adding and Removing Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/add-applications/C/index.html)**

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu Manual you can Download for free or buy it http://ubuntu-manual.org/ (in many language).

Answer (score 1):

This may seem odd suggestion, but as i see, you are also a developer and you are used to do things by trial and error.

So best thing may be to just install ubuntu and dive in, most of the stuff is easy.
Next thing to do would be too google best/must-have/(anything of this kind) ubuntu/linux apps and open couple of pages, you could also specify some specific app category.

Learn what sudo command is, how to execute scripts (sh).
And one beginner advice, this kind of annoyed me, if you need admin permission for some file managment, you can do

```
sudo nautilus
```

I met lots of people who asked me how to log in as root, and all they wanted is to have admin rights in file manager.

Answer (score 1):

These books might also be useful:

- [Are there any good books for new Ubuntu users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1874/are-there-any-good-books-for-new-ubuntu-user)
- [List of free Ubuntu books](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575/list-of-free-ubuntu-books)