# Guides for Ubuntu Software

Tags: documentation

As I mentioned in previous questions I am setting up a computer lab for a charity that deals with orphans in Tanzania Africa. One thing that would be very helpful are eBook/PDF guides for Ubuntu software. Keep in mind some of the kids have never used a computer, so what is basic for us is foreign for them. We will be running: LibreOffice, Inkscape, Gimp, Gnucash, Audacity, Scribus, VLC, Blender, Pidgin, ClamAV, VirtualBox, Wine, Firefox, Chrome, Thunderbird, 7zip, OpenShot Video Editor. Please let me know about any guides about using Ubuntu itself or other software you feel would be helpful.

Comment: Yes I did check out that other question, good guides to Ubuntu itself but none of the applications. Many of the kids can read English.

Comment: LibreOffice has a user manual in PDF and ODT formats: https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/documentation/

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet will be the

- [Ubuntu Manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org/downloads)

Note though that it deals with 10.10, not 11.04. There's also a version of the book for 10.04. But: it's absolutely excellent, and on the perfect level for your purposes.

If it matters for you: the book, unfortunately, is not available in Swahili.

See also:

- [List of free Ubuntu books](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575/list-of-free-ubuntu-books)