# Free online Ubuntu user guide, that is simple to understand?

Tags: documentation

I just recently downloaded and started using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and this is my first Linux/unix OS ever. I've been faced with a gigantic learning curve that I think would deter most people.

With that in mind, is there a free "Ubuntu for dummies" type website/article/guide somewhere?
I mean, something that would even be as simple as to describe the difference between the windows file storage tabulation (C:\Windows...etc) vs Linux tabulation (etc/default/... etc etc etc).

I am often researching things on how to improve / fix my Ubuntu and am rapidly confused because the help forums make basic assumptions about ideas like this. I don't necessarily already know where the "etc" folder is. I didn't even know what **Nautilus** was even though I had already been using it.
These are my problems.

Is there such a guide? One which will be simple, and easy to understand? One which will be free of charge?

Comment: Take a look here too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/575/list-of-free-ubuntu-books

Comment: Also you can refer the Inbuilt Ubuntu help[Ubuntu Desktop Guide].

Comment: in general i like what the potential offers in ubuntu, but I need a dictionary to figure what is referred to as what. If the community really wants more users they have got to make the process for "not being left out" really a welcoming one. If the community believes in it and wants it to succeed they must help without condescending the newbies into the fold.I hear the naysayers , yet, I am just saying what appears obvious...

Comment: I take umbrage at some of the edits...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many manuals on the internet, but you can begin with the following.

1.- Browse the [ubuntuguide.org](http://ubuntuguide.org) with many wikipedia-style articles and how-to's.

[image]

2.- Download the book [Getting started with Ubuntu](http://ubuntu-manual.org/downloads).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The best way of learning an OS, I feel, is playing around with it for a while. For a while, can mean a few weeks to few years too! There are documentations available but then they might as well make you feel bored than teaching you something worth while, unless you love reading a lot! This is one of the official ones, I found with a quick Google search:
[Learning Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Learning/UbuntuDesktopTopics)
Yes, many of us don't know that the GUI for navigating in folders in 12.04 is nautilus but that is fine when you begin learning; that is primarily because we are used to using Windows, which integrated everything into it without giving it a peculiar name. You'll learn as you continue using it. You'll surely find it adventurous to play around with Ubuntu. Enjoy!

Comment: I have to both agree and disagree with this.
I agree in that I enjoy playing with Ubuntu and seeing what I can do (especially, and potentially horrifically, the terminal)
On the other hand... sometimes I'm just trying to figure something out and then I just want to hulk smash my laptop... which is bad. 
Also, I like reading things like Diana Hacker's "Writer's Reference" for fun.... so... reading how to use my new OS sounds fascinating and useful to me.

Comment: Get going then @Arammil, hope you enjoy on it as much you read about it! :)