# New to UBUNTU, need a learning experience

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

I  am quite new to UBUNTU. I have just read a book on UNIX. I have no practical experience about working on Linux. Can anyone help me out on how do I go about,installing it on my machine(laptop). Which is presently running Windows 7.I am a bit worried about losing the previously important files, in case things go wrong.Yes, I am lagging a bit of confidence, to be specific.:p

Comment: Although Linux and Unix are very similar, they are not quite the same, and distributions differ. For example, Ubuntu (Linux), Android (Linux) and Apple's OSX (Unix) are quite different. I suggest that you search the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/), especially the [Absolute Beginners Section](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=326), where this question has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: Why not go to [the IRC channel for Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/chat) and chat to people with instant messaging? You can even do that directly from your browser by [clicking here](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=ubuntu).

Comment: google is your friend

Comment: This question is ambiguous, vague, and overly broad. It cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. If you worry about losing important files make backups, copies etc. For installation help, search for Ubuntu installation. Start at ubuntu.com

Comment: Youtube is a GREAT source for this kind of information, the good thing is that you can actually see how the theory works.

Comment: Check [Free Ubuntu start-up guides](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233900/free-online-ubuntu-user-guide-that-is-simple-to-understand/233905#233905)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to install it on your machine in order to try it. There's what are called "Live CDs" or "Live USBs" that you can boot from, run Ubuntu **wihtout any modification to your existing system** (*unless, of course, you actively erase or modify your files*), and when you reboot again the original OS comes back unmodified.

You can check this guide on the official ubuntu site on [how to try ubuntu befor you install it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).

Answer (score -1):

The #Ubuntu-beginners and #Ubuntu channels in IRC are great, I hang out in there all day.  Always active.