# I think I've been hacked, what can I do?

Tags: networking

I have recently installed Ubuntu 15.xx and I belive my machine has been hacked.

My computer's name has been changed to `imatransvestite`, and although I can still change passwords, I cannot use `sudo` without this error: `sudo: unable to resolve host imatransvestite`

What can I do to fix tis, and what should I do?

Comment: have you configured a root password ?

Comment: Reinstall from scratch.  Configure the firewall when your installation is completed, and don't use untrusted wireless networks or websites (that's likely a vector for how you got hacked)

Comment: @maetsoh Yes I had a password

Comment: when I type sudo or any command that is using sudo this is the answer
"sudo: unable to resolve host imatransvestite"

Comment: See @ThomasW. 's advice + you'll need to find out first how you were hacked. Highly unlikely under normal circumstances.

Comment: Close Voters: This is not really "too broad" in so much that if they are hacked it's time to 'nuke the system'.  My answer gives them a course of action.  We do not need to close this as 'broad'

Comment: Similar: http://askubuntu.com/q/601869/178596 . I think there was another one where the 'Nuke em from orbit' method was suggested

Comment: Your hacker a a strange sense of humour...

Comment: Highly relevant: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/q/218005/58408) on [sf].

Comment: I've still not come up with a better way of putting it than that, @MichaelKjörling - but people want the "one weird trick to making your server be like it was never hacked in the first place".

Comment: If your system has been hacked @albvik then you should be thinking about what information might have been compromised and the possible consequences of that. Is this a personal system with personal data? A server that might hold customer data or could be serving trojanised webpages to visitors? This is potentially more valuable to your attackers (and to yourself) than the simple fact of the hack itself.

Comment: @RobM I don't currently own any "precious data" on my laptop :) , I got only programming books and stuff like that. I've just begun my journey into cyber-security stuff.

Comment: @albvik Welcome to a lesson you should have learned a long time ago. No, this is not a slight. No matter what anyone else said, this is important and I want you to remember this. Security is a process - not an application. The largest vector for vulnerabilities is in the chair -- not in the code. As others have said, nothing on your system can be presumed safe now. Nothing... Learn good backup processes and strictly follow them no matter how tedious they seem. Use strong passwords, keep minimal ports available, and use least permissions. Never make assumptions except to assume it is unsafe.

Comment: Reinstalling from scratch is good advice but for any more relevant advice you'd have to give more specific details in the question to narrow it down a bit: for example, are you on a home network, what was the network setup, what do you know about who "hacked" you, etc.  For instance, did you little brother simply log in as you using the password he already knows you use ... or was this a secure password and nobody else had physical access ... ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have been hacked, or even think you have been hacked, then there is ***no easy way*** to determine what all has been done to your system.

In your case, we know that, at the very least, your system's hostname has been changed.  However, a backdoor for the hacker could have been installed.  Malware could have been installed.  Your system could be configured to use poisoned DNS.  You could have malware that's downloading very very NSFW illegal things to your computer.  There is *literally* an unending list of things your computer could be doing as a result of being hacked..

Your best solution is to **"Nuke It From Orbit"**<sup>TM</sup>, or in laymans terms, ***"Completely reinstall from scratch".***

In addition to reinstalling your system from scratch, take the following steps:

1. **Change all your passwords on websites you use**.  It's possible your passwords are now in the hands of the hacker, so time to use different ones.
2. **Set up a firewall.**  After you have a cleanly installed system, run the following commands, to make sure that a firewall is installed and enabled.  This will help secure your system:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ufw
   sudo ufw enable
   ```
3. **Only use networks and websites which you trust to not be malicious.**  Unsecured wireless networks are a hacker's paradise, and untrusted sites can have malware or other privacy-violating things on them that can lead to you being hacked.
4. **Use different passwords for every login, and use a password manager to manage/remember them**.  Make sure a password manager's password doesn't match another password you use, and make sure all your passwords are different.  This applies for your user account too going forward.  This is one of the most effective methods, but it's a little more difficult.

Comment: Isn't UFW installed and enabled by default? Or only on newer versions?

Comment: @ByteCommander all the ones I've seen, 14.04+, `ufw` is installed, but I don't think it's enabled.  I'm rebuilding my Ubuntu VMs to test, but it never hurts to put it in the list of things to do anyways.  Because **always verifying** is better than not.

Comment: That's for sure. But I can't remember having it manually installed on my new 15.10, but it's enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you've been hacked, then your number one priority should be to determine the attack vector -- otherwise it will just end up happening again.  Before wiping the system and reinstalling everything, back up any relevant logs and review them.  If your attacker did not wipe the logs, then you should have a pretty fair idea of how they got in and what your first steps should be when you do reinstall your system.