# How can I find the origin of a process and stop it permanently?

Tags: apache2, malware, hacking

I have an Ubuntu system running an apache server. I have found a process `cache.sh` which I think might be a crypto-mining process and which is running all the time on my server consuming up to 98% CPU. This is causing other stuff to stop working like MySQL and apache.

I used the `top` command to find out that `cache.sh` is consuming all the CPU.

I have tried killing the process but it starts running again after some time.

I then learned that I could pause the process instead of killing it and that works quite well but I still want to find out what it is and get rid of it permanently. After restarting the whole server this process starts automatically.

The process `cache.sh` is running under www-data user, which is also responsible for handling the apache process which runs under the same user.

What could I do to find the origin of this process and to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I think I've been hacked, what can I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694351/i-think-ive-been-hacked-what-can-i-do)

Comment: You can use the `lsof` command to find the files that are opened by the running process. This will help you the find the directory where the `cache.sh` file is located. Usage: `lsof -p PID` , where PID is the actual PID of the process.

Comment: `locate cache.sh` will find the file. `dlocate -S cache.sh` will let you know if it came from a package.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the `/proc` directory for the cache.sh process. Each process has a `/proc/<pid>/` directory where it keeps information like:

- *cwd* – link to the *c*urrent *w*orking *d* irectory
- *fd* – a directory with links to the open files (*f*ile *d*escriptors)
- *cmdline* – read it to see what command line was used to start the process
- *environ* – the environment variables for that process
- *root* – a link to what the process considers its root directory. It will be `/` unless chrooted.

Running `ps auxf` will show you who forked what, so you may get a better idea what is calling your process.

Running `lsof -p PID` shows the files that are opened by the running process.

<sub>**Source:** [Linux: How to know where a process was started and how it was started?](https://serverfault.com/questions/232762/linux-how-to-know-where-a-process-was-started-and-how-it-was-started/233250#233250)</sub>